# How to align cells to center?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code selects the sheet but fails to align the cells to center:

```vb
wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:L").Select
With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

wb.Sheets(1).Activate
wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:L").Select
With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```

Selects the entire sheet but it's not changing the vertical alignment to center.

```vb
wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:L").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
```

I don't want HorizontalAlignment.

I found the column has VerticalAlignment set to xlCenter but the Cells underneath the column do not have VerticalAlignment set to xlCenter.

Comment: This code will work whenever `wb.Sheets(1)` is the active worksheet otherwise it will fail.  I am upvoting this question because it is a common trap for people learning to program VBA through recording macros.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't `Select` and don't work with `Selection` without a reason. That's Recorder's stuff.  It is longer to read, slower to execute, and prone to error.

`wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:L").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter`  is much better.

If you need to do several things with the same range, then use `With`

```
with wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:L")
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
      .somethingElse
End with
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a common error for those newly learning the Excel object model.  Every worksheet must have a current selected range, but `Selection` always points to the selected range on the *active* worksheet.  You have to `.Activate` a sheet for the selected range on that sheet to be the `Selection` object.

```
wb.Sheets(1).Activate
wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:L").Select
With Selection
  .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
```

Or you could change your code to not rely on the `Selection` object:

```
wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:L").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter` with `.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked perfect

```
With Hoja.Range("A1:O1")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = 12
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 208, 0)
    .Font.Color = RGB(26, 20, 70)
End With
```

Comment: are you providing a solution to the question? it seems from your response it is somebody's else solution. Please clarify it.